# C# UI for AWS S3 not updating

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

I am creating a download application in C# that downloads files from Amazon AWS S3 storage. I am able to download the file without issue, but I am trying to create a progress event.

To create the event I am using the following code within the download function:

```
Application.DoEvents();
response2.WriteObjectProgressEvent += displayProgress;
Application.DoEvents();
```

The event handler I created is as follows:

```
private void displayProgress(object sender, WriteObjectProgressArgs args)
{
    // Counter for Event runs
    label7.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label7.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(label7.Text)+1).ToString()));

    Application.DoEvents(); 
    // transferred bytes
    label4.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label4.Text = args.TransferredBytes.ToString()));

    Application.DoEvents();
    // progress bar
    progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value = args.PercentDone));

    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

The issue is that it only updates when a file it downloaded, but the event runs more often.  When I download the last file (12MB); lable7 (event counter) jumps from 3 to 121, so I know it is running, but just not updating.

I have also tried just a 'standard' Invoke, but I had the same result.

Additional Code of the function:

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    ServiceURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
};

var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(stuff, stuff, S3Config);

ListBucketsResponse response = s3Client.ListBuckets();

GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
request.BucketName = "dr-test";
request.Key = locationoffile[currentdownload];


GetObjectResponse response2 = s3Client.GetObject(request);

response2.WriteObjectProgressEvent += displayProgress;


string pathlocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) + "\\" + Instrument[currentdownload] + "\\" + NewFileName[currentdownload];

response2.WriteResponseStreamToFile(pathlocation);
```

Comment: Have you tried it without all the DoEvents calls?

Comment: Yes, I tried with just 1 call, then I tried with 3, next I tried with 0, and finally I just did one after every line.  Did not work any way I tried.

Comment: Are you using the async version of the download method?

Comment: No the call is occurring in a loop from a button click.  It is not async.  I put the code at the bottom of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the asynchronous call for `GetObject` or `WriteResponseStreamToFile`, so the UI thread (that you're calling it from) is going to be blocked, which means that it can't update the progress (regardless of those `DoEvents` calls, which are generally considered evil and you should avoid).

Without actually being able to try it myself, here's what I think you need to do.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(...download....in files to download){

        AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            ServiceURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
        };

        var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(stuff, stuff, S3Config);

        ListBucketsResponse response = s3Client.ListBuckets();

        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
        request.BucketName = "dr-test";
        request.Key = locationoffile[currentdownload];



        GetObjectResponse response2 = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request, null);

        response2.WriteObjectProgressEvent += displayProgress;



        string pathlocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) + "\\" + Instrument[currentdownload] + "\\" + NewFileName[currentdownload];

        await response2.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(pathlocation, null);

  }
 }
```

The two `null`s that I added are for cancellation tokens, I can't tell from the AWS docs if it's allowed to pass a null token, if not please create one and pass it in.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to only change the WriteResponceStream line, and I did have to create a cancellation token.  After that it worked without issue.